# U.S Laws on Cookie Notices on Websites?

Tags: united-states, internet

I'm working on a website that will use cookies. I heard that by law I have to add a notice "somewhere" on my site to tell people that it uses cookies and I have to include a page with instructions on how to disable cookies with various browsers. Ive asked people and searched the web for the law about this in the U.S but I only fnd stuff for the EU and that I have to follow EU's laws or I'll be fined. I really don't want to worry about adding this stuff to my website especially since it will not work like how it's​ supposed to with cookies disabled. What are the requirements for cookies in the U.S and if any, how am I supposed to present the notice on my site?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no US law on this.

However, you will have to comply with EU law unless you have some way of preventing anyone in the EU from accessing the parts of your site that use cookies.

Comment: But what would the EU do about it? The domain and website is in the US and all is managed by US citizens, what could the EU do about?

Comment: They could file suit against you, obtain a judgement, file that judgement in a US court, the US court would probably give effect to it, they would then pursue you for the debt. Is this likely? No. Is it possible? Yes. It is almost a certainty that they will sue *someone* in a foreign jurisdiction just to show their laws have teeth.